# angularjs how to push array to add dynamic form fields

Tags: angularjs, nested, dynamic-forms

Hi I am new to Angularjs please help i am trying to create a dynamic form field my html is like this

```
<div ng-repeat="cb in categories">
  <div ng-repeat="choice in cb.choices">
    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.req_goods">
    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.qty">
    <button ng-hide="$first" ng-click="removeChoice($parent.$index,$index)">-</button>
  </div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="addNewChoice($index)">+</button>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$scope.categories = [
{
  "id":1,
   "name":"Furniture & Fixture",
   "choices":[
   {
      "req_goods":"table",
       "qty":"4"
    }]
 },
 {
   "id":2,
   "name":"Miscellaneous Property",
   "choices":[
   {
      "req_goods":"others",
      "qty":"6"
   }]
}];

$scope.addNewChoice = function(id){
            $scope.categories.choices[id].push({});
};
```

I want to add choices dynamically when user click add button. I tried above `addNewChoice()` function but it gives error `angular.min.js:114 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"` please help i am really tense as i am trying this from yeterday. thank you

Comment: try `$scope.categories[id].choices.push({ "req_goods":"", "qty":"" });`

Comment: exactly thank you can you help me removing  (splice) the array please

Comment: i did it $scope.categories[parent_id].choices.splice(id,1); thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
    $scope.categories[id].choices
```

it will correct  your error

Answer (score 1):

As @Ranjith J said, you must change your code to

```
$scope.categories[id].choices.push({})
```

When you pass `$index` as a parameter in `ng-click="addNewChoice($index)"`, you are referring to the categories index. So it makes sense to use your `id` parameter to access the right category.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/halirgb/Lvc0u55v/) for a working example.